# Having a Problem Testing my Solidity Smart Contract (w/ Truffle)

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, truffle, consensys-truffle

So Im building a basic NF Token. Created a basic minting function and mapping. Im testing the app with truffle, tried both solidity testing and JS testing. Having the following errors.

```
Using network 'development'.

Compiling ./contracts/NFCertificate.sol...
Compiling ./node_modules/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/AddressUtils.sol...
Compiling ./node_modules/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/introspection/ERC165.sol...
Compiling ./node_modules/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/introspection/SupportsInterfaceWithLookup.sol...
Compiling ./node_modules/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol...
Compiling ./node_modules/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/ownership/Ownable.sol...
Compiling ./node_modules/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721Basic.sol...
Compiling ./node_modules/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721BasicToken.sol...
Compiling ./node_modules/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721Receiver.sol...
Compiling ./test/TestCertificate.sol...
Compiling truffle/Assert.sol...
Compiling truffle/DeployedAddresses.sol...

Compilation warnings encountered:

/Users/aditya/Desktop/Work & Hobbies/Ideas/Blockchain/Blockchain Development/Ethereum:dApp/CertificateContract/contracts/NFCertificate.sol:26:35: Warning: This function only accepts a single "bytes" argument. Please use "abi.encodePacked(...)" or a similar function to encode the data.
        uint256 tokenId = uint256(keccak256(certificateNum, msg.sender, title, message));
                                  ^---------------------------------------------------^



  TestCertificate
    1) testNumber
    > No events were emitted

  Contract: NFCertificate
    2) It should return the same number
    > No events were emitted


  0 passing (1s)
  2 failing

  1) TestCertificate
       testNumber:
     Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert
      at Object.InvalidResponse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/errors.js:38:1)
      at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/requestmanager.js:86:1
      at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-provider/wrapper.js:134:1
      at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/httpprovider.js:128:1)
      at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:64:1)
      at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:354:1)
      at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:509:1)
      at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:469:1)
      at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1081:12)
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)

  2) Contract: NFCertificate
       It should return the same number:
     TypeError: instance.returnNumbers is not a function
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/TestCertificate.js:9:31)
      at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-core/lib/testing/testrunner.js:135:1
      at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/property.js:119:1
      at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/requestmanager.js:89:1
      at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-provider/wrapper.js:134:1
      at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/httpprovider.js:128:1)
      at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:64:1)
      at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:354:1)
      at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:509:1)
      at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:469:1)
      at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1081:12)
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

The test scripts are running a simple internal function in the contract that returns an int = 1000 and compares that to the expected variable (let expected = 1000) declared in the test. Heres the JS test script

```
  import assertRevert from "zeppelin- 
  solidity/test/helpers/assertRevert";

  const NFCertificate = artifacts.require("NFCertificate");

  contract("NFCertificate", () => {
      it("It should return the same number", function() {
          let instance = NFCertificate.deployed();
          let expected = 1000;
          assert.equal(instance.returnNumber(), expected);
      });
  });
```

Heres the Solidity Test Script:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.20;

import "truffle/Assert.sol";
import "truffle/DeployedAddresses.sol";
import "../contracts/NFCertificate.sol";

contract TestCertificate {

  function testNumber() public {
    NFCertificate cert = NFCertificate(DeployedAddresses.NFCertificate());
    uint expected = 1000;
    Assert.equal(cert.returnNumber(), expected, "Numbers should be equal");
  }
}
```

I also tried testing minted token ID's, and also owners of tokens based on the mapping I declared, Im getting the same problem. **When writing a test contract in javascript it can't recognize the functions in the original NFT contract. When writing a test contract in solidity it almost always says "Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert" and nothing else.**

Finally here's the contract im trying to test out. Any and all help is appreciated, im very new to coding and ethereum so I've probably made numerous mistakes.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

import '../node_modules/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721BasicToken.sol';
import '../node_modules/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/ownership/Ownable.sol';

contract NFCertificate is ERC721BasicToken, Ownable {
    struct Certificate {
        uint certNum;
        uint256 tokenId;
        bytes32 title;
        bytes32 message;
        address owner;
    }

    mapping (uint256 => address) tokenToOwner;
    mapping (address => uint256) ownerToToken;
    mapping (uint256 => string) tokenIdToName;

    event returnNumbers(uint number);

    Certificate[] public certificates;

    function createCert(bytes32 title, bytes32 message) public returns (bytes32){
        uint certificateNum = certificates.length - 1; 
        uint256 tokenId = uint256(keccak256(certificateNum, msg.sender, title, message));
        certificates.push(Certificate(certificateNum++, tokenId, title, message, msg.sender));
        tokenToOwner[tokenId] = msg.sender;
        ownerToToken[msg.sender] = tokenId;
        _mint(msg.sender, tokenId);
    }

    function returnNumber() public returns(uint) {
        uint number = 1000;
        returnNumbers(number);
        return number;
    }

    function whatTokensDoYouOwn(address owner) public view returns(uint256) {
        return ownerToToken[owner]; 
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NFCertificate.deployed()` returns a promise, as does `instance.returnNumber()`. So the JS should be:

```
contract("NFCertificate", () => {
  it("It should return the same number", async function() {
      let instance = await NFCertificate.deployed();
      let expected = 1000;
      assert.equal(await instance.returnNumber(), expected);
  });
});
```

As `returnNumbers` is an event, it should be emitted using the `emit` keyword. It's also good to style events to start with a capital, otherwise it might look like a function. So `event ReturnNumbers(uint number);`

```
function returnNumber() public returns(uint) {
    uint number = 1000;
    emit ReturnNumbers(number);
    return number;
}
```

Adding the async/await lines should fix your JavaScript tests. If you later want to assert that your `ReturnNumbers` events were emitted correctly, I would suggest to use my [`truffle-assertions`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/truffle-assertions) library, which includes functions to assert that events have or have not been emitted. It also includes functions to assert reverts and other failures in a straightforward way.